# Sort List using Filename

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, listbox, system.io.fileinfo

i have a program where i need to list the files in my Listbox like the way windows Sort the files

i have this code

but it doesn't sort the Files properly

```
public ObservableCollection<string> FileNames { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    var lstfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(SelectedPath, "*").Select(fn => new FileInfo(fn)).OrderBy(f => f.Name);
                foreach (var item in lstfiles)
                {
                    FileNames.Add(item.ToString());
                }
```

my filenames are integer

```
1.pdf
2.pdf
3.pdf
4.pdf
...
4000.pdf
```

the program sort it this way

```
1.pdf
99.pdf
143.pdf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort list using digits in file name like below.

```
lstFiles = lstFiles.OrderByDescending(x=> int.Parse(Regex.Replace(x,"[^0-9]+","0"))).ToList<string>();
```

fiddler : https://dotnetfiddle.net/RHzdm2